# Как разделить массив на несколько частей, где 1 число массива - кол-во элементов, которые нужно поместить в массив?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, .net

Допустим у нас на вход идёт массив `[2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 8, 1, 2]`. Первое число является количеством последующих элементов, которые нужно поместить в массив, а за ней следуют элементы этого массива, и возврающаются отдельные массивы.
Как его разделить на подмассивы которые будут выглядеть как `[5, 6]`, `[4, 5 8]`, `[2]`?

Comment: Уточните, что должно быть результатом - массив массивов, List массивов, ещё что-то? Если вы это уже определили, то что препятствует созданию?

Comment: Есть решение из коробки с LInq Chunk. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-7.0

Comment: @c942o Это не то, здесь куски разной длины

Comment: Вы можете приняь ответ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Моё предложение реализации:

```
public static IEnumerable<int[]> Arr(int[] data) {
    for (int p = 0; p < data.Length;) {

        int d = data[p++];    // Получаем размер массива

        d = (d <= 0) ? 0 : d; // Если размер не корректный, то правим
        int[] arr = new int[d]; // Создаём массив

        for(var i = 0; i < d && p < data.Length; i++, p++)
            arr[i] = data[p];   // Заполняем массив данными

        yield return arr;       // Результат
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var data = new int[] {2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 8, 1, 2};
    var source = Arr( data );

    foreach (var numarr in source) {
        numarr.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write( "{0} ", i));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
5 6 
4 5 8 
2
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/SeM3pT

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень точное и лаконичное решение) использовал ваш код, чтобы переделать под свою изначальную задачу. Может кому пригодится https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75065291/how-to-process-data-in-passed-to-function-in-a-channel/75065602#75065602